# How to insert data to text file with using NSFileHandle

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsfilehandle

My code replaces text instead of inserting it starting from 5 symbol:

```
NSFileHandle *file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: filePath];
[file seekToFileOffset: 5];

[file writeData: [value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Is there any way to insert data to text file?

Comment: Well, accordingly to this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593418/inserting-a-string-at-a-specified-line-in-text-file-using-objective-c), it's impossible :(

Answer (score 0):

That's because your code set the index `position to 5` and start writing from there, thus replacing everything from `5` onwards.

I would copy the content of the file to a variable and modify it from there as a `string`. 
as by the looks of it what you attempt to do [is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593418/inserting-a-string-at-a-specified-line-in-text-file-using-objective-c)

**Update:** 
Given that what you need is to write from X offset this should do the trick

```
   NSFileHandle *file;
        NSMutableData *data;

        const char *bytestring = "black dog";

        data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:bytestring length:strlen(bytestring)];


        file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: @"/tmp/quickfox.txt"];

        if (file == nil)
                NSLog(@"Failed to open file");


        [file seekToFileOffset: 10];

        [file writeData: data];

        [file closeFile];
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that. The question is how to *insert* test from position 5, (not to *replace*)

Answer (score 0):

Well this might not be an efficient way, but you could read the entire text file into an NSMutableString and then use insertString:atIndex: and then write it back out. As far as I know there is no way to insert text into an existing file. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033060/c-function-to-insert-text-at-particular-location-in-file-without-over-writing-th)

A quick example:

```
NSString *path = //Your file
NSMutableString *contents = [NSMutableString stringWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];

[contents insertString:@"Some string to insert" atIndex:5];
[contents writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting data somewhere in a sequential file would require that the entire file be rewritten.  It is possible, however, to add data to the end of a file without rewriting the file.